# Recursive program for power - Efficiency

Tags: c, performance, recursion

Do you have any ideas how can I make my program more efficient?

```
double recPow(double x, int y) {

if (y == 0)
    return 1.0;
if (y < 0 && x == 0)
    return x/0;
if (y < 0)
    whenNegPow(x, y);
if (y % 2 == 1)
    return x * recPow(x, y / 2) * recPow(x, y / 2);
else
    return recPow(x, y / 2) * recPow(x, y / 2);
}
```

I was thinking about something like

```
double ret= recPow(x,y/2) * recPow(x,y/2);
```

and then returning either `x*ret` or `ret`..

are there any better ways to improve my efficieny?

Thanks!

Comment: `return x/0;` What?

Comment: That will return inf. It was asked in the paperwork.. nothing to do with the efficiency haha @EdwardKarak

Answer (score 2):

Another possible optimization is to compute `recPow(x,y/2)` only once.

```
double a = recPow(x, y / 2)
if (y % 2 == 1)
    return x * a * a;
else
    return a * a;
```

Comment: But when I do it, a will get an actual value, and then the recursion will stop, or did I miss something ?

Comment: You will recursively call recPow with y/2 at each call. This has the nice property to be O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (y < 0)
    return 1 / recPow (x, -y);
```

Comment: whenNegPow does that

Comment: What does this code do? Why is it an improvement over the original code? Provide some context and explanation to answers to make them useful.

Comment: the function must return an integer, in his code if (y < 0) it doesn't, it's just calling the function, also no need to write a new function to do that.

Comment: WhenNegPow is a function that assists me to handle the case of negative exponent.. I surely can write it like you did I just didn't like it ..

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is not too efficient by design - it intensively uses stack. Using the loop is much better and more efficient.
The algorithm below should be faster (it uses maximum 32 iterations only):

```
#define INT_BITS (4 * 8)
double recPow(double x, int y) {
    if (y == 0)
        return 1.0;
    if (y < 0)
        return 1.0 / recPow(x, -y);
    double res = 1.0;
    int y1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < INT_BITS; i++) {
        if (y & 0x1) {
            res *= x;
            y1++;
        }
        if (y == y1)
            break;
        x *= x;
        y >>= 1;
        y1 <<= 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```